# How to see implementation of code in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to see code when I click on method. I click ctrl + click but it takes me and show only comments / names of methods, is there a possibility to see real implementation?

Comment: Is this of a method you wrote, or from a framework/library?

Comment: @gunr2171 it is for library, framework, for example isDevelopment in startup.cs

Comment: Do you have the source code? Can you open the file with the source? That's how you see it. There are tools that let you "look inside" .NET assemblies, but I don't that's what you're talking about

Comment: @Flydog57
 I just want to see implementation of some methods which are out of the box

Comment: Your description does make me understand what you are talking about. What does _"implementation of some methods which are out of the box"_ mean?

Comment: If you use .NET5/.NET6, look at https://github.com/dotnet, if it is .NET Framework: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: I suggest taking @KlausGütter's comment as an answer. Of course, you can answer it yourself! See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use .NET5/.NET6, look at http://github.com/dotnet.

If it is .NET Framework: http://referencesource.microsoft.com.